# Jolt - Remove last element from array

Tags: json, jolt

After some jolt shift and default operations I'm left with

```
"items" : [ null, "-70.7", "-70.4", "-68.5", null, "tmp" ]
```

The last thing I want to achieve is remove this "tmp" string from the array.

Any ideas how to achieve that? I've already tried different things but no results :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **shift** transformation through combining indexes of the array except for the *last element* by **pipe**(**|**) operators such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "0|1|2|3|4": {
          "@": "&2.[&1]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The demo on http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ :

[image]

A dynamical solution might be successive transformations, also through adding **modify** transformation.

An extra conversion from **`null`** to **`"null"`** is performed in the below specification to apply the technique of exchanging the key and value pairs in order to prevent the extinction issue of **`null`** values such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": ["=toString", "null"],
      "sz_items": "=size(@(1,items))",
      "sz_items_minus_1": "=intSum(-1,@(1,sz_items))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "[&].@(0)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "items[@(0)]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The demo :

[image]

or the more dynamical solution, even *keeping* **null** values might be

```json
[
  //determine the length of the lists(arrays) except for the rightmost element
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "sz_items": "=size(@(1,items))",
      "sz_items_minus_1": "=intSum(-1,@(1,sz_items))"
    }
  },
  //get rid of unnecessary attribute
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "sz_items": ""
    }
  },
  //determine the rightmost element as a list
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "items.&"
      },
      "@": "xxx"
    }
  },
  //convert the values of the elements of the "items" to lists 
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": "=toList(@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  //determine the length of the elements of the "items" to lists 
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": ["=size(@(1,&))", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  //filter out generated elements with multiple component(eg. keep 0 or 1)
  //in order to reform the list
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "xxx": {
        "items": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,&1.&)": {
              "0|1": { "@2": "&4[&3]" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @Nice try, but the list is dynamic, so number of elements might be different. I want to remove the last element.

Comment: Thanks again but I cannot convert null to "null".